# How access event listeners of an object instantiated on runtime in java swing

Tags: java, swing, variables, subclass, event-listener

I have a custom made JPanel `itemSmallCard(String prodID, String productName, String price, String retailer)`, using this I created multiple instances of it in another JPanel with different parameters on the ActionPerformed event of a button as follows:

```java
JPanel iC = new itemSmallCard("123456789ab", "Inspiron 7567 Intel Core i5 DELL Laptop", "48957", "Cloudtail Pvt. Ltd.");
        mainContentPane.add(iC);
        mainContentPane.revalidate();
        mainContentPane.repaint();
```

However as all the new JPanels were created with this same code using the same variable `iC`,  I don't know how to access a particular JPanel variable from them, thus also unable to access its event listeners.
How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps create an ArrayList (if you don't need to access specific ones not based on location).

```java
ArrayList<JPanel> panels = new ArrayList<JPanel>();
```

Or, if you need to access them, you could make a "HashMap" and store the ID you have in there.

```java
WeakHashMap<String, JPanel> panels = new WeakHashMap<String, JPanel>();

panels.put("123456789ab", new itemSmallCard("123456789ab", "Inspiron 7567 Intel Core i5 DELL Laptop", "48957", "Cloudtail Pvt. Ltd.");// Adds a product with that info

panels.get("123456789ab"); // Returns the panel with that ID.
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write a generic listener:

1. in the listener code you use the `getSource()` method to get the source of the event.
2. Once you know the source component you can use the `getParent()` method of the component.
3. Now you have access to the panel and you can access any method/variable of the panel.